# Using Google's ImageWorker to load images in ListView results in java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, caching, memory-management, android-listview, bitmap

Recently, I started using Google ImageWorker class for loading bitmaps on a background thread. This class handles everything, including putting the bitmaps in the ImageView. Google talks about this class (and it's helper classes for Image manipulation and caching) here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

The ImageView(s) in my case are parts of list items in a ListView. Here's the interesting part of getView on my ArrayAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView == null ? inflater.inflate(R.layout.nodelist_item, null) : convertView;
    NodeHolder holder = getHolder(view);

    Node node = mList.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(node.Title);
    //Setting the rest of the different fields ...

    //And finally loading the image
    if(node.hasArt())
        worker.loadImage(node.ImageID, holder.imgIcon);
}
```

The entire getView method can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/CJbtVfij

The worker object is a very simple implementation of the ImageWorker:

```
public class NodeArtWorker extends ImageWorker {

    protected int width;
    protected int height;

    public NodeArtWorker(Context context) {
        super(context);
        addImageCache(context);
        //Code for getting the approximate width and height of the ImageView, in order to scale to save memory.
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap processBitmap(Object data) {
        Bitmap b = getBitmap(data);
        if(b == null) return null;
        return Utils.resizeBitmap(b, width, height);
    }

    protected Bitmap getBitmap(Object data) {
        //Downloads the bitmap from a server, and returns it.
    }
}
```

This works very well, and the performance is much better now than before. However, if I change the ImageID on some of the items in the list, and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to rebuild the view (and thereby start loading new bitmaps), I get a RuntimeException:

```
0   java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@41adf448
1   at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:1058)
2   at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1159)
3   at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:440)
4   at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1025)
5   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14126)
```

The full stacktrace can be seen in the following pastebin entry, but is probably uninteresting, as it is the typical Android view hierarchy redraw stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/DsWcidqw

I get that the Bitmaps are being recycled, but I don't understand exactly where and what can be done about it. As my code comes directly from Google, and is, as far as I understand, the recommended way of doing this, I am very confused.

Comment: Can you describe the `Node` and `NodeHolder` structure

Comment: It's in the pastebin right below the first code block. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android, `Bitmap`s can be recycled to be later re-used (much faster than re-creating a Bitmap).
The `Bitmap#recycle()`method will flag the Bitmap as recycled.
So if you try to set such a recycled bitmap to an ImageView or draw it on a Canvas, you will end up with this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap

The official demo that you linked on your question is dealing with recycled `Bitmap`s.
It uses a dedicated method `hasValidBitmap()` and checks the `Bitmap#isRecycled()` value:

```
private synchronized boolean hasValidBitmap() {
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap();
    return bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled();
}
```

So you need to do the same. When you're searching on your cache for a Bitmap, before applying it to an ImageView, check if it's recycled or not. If it's not you can directly set it, otherwise, you need to update the Bitmap.

To create a new Bitmap from a recycled Bitmap, you can use the [Bitmap::createBitmap(Bitmap)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)) method.

You can find more details on [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html).

Comment: You're probably right. I tried the Picasso image loading library instead, which seems to work without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is not the `ImageWorker class` bug, this is

`com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView.dispatchDraw(DragSortListView.java:797)`

issue. so in order to see my answer is correct or not just remove that library and see if it works or not. after that i think the best solutions are:

1- not use that library.

2- report issue on github.

3- solve it by your own and debugge it.

4- or you can set null for image holder bitmap

```
holder.imgIcon.setBitmapDrawble(null);
```

and then call `worker.loadImage`.

Comment: This too might be correct, but I have changed to using the Picasso image loading library instead of Google's, and this seems to work (even though I'm still using the DragSortListView).

Comment: Picasso may handle bitmap recycling at a different moment so the `DragSortListView` can use it with out any problem.